# What to do when interface implementation does not provide async

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, task

Let's say I have an interface:

```
interface ILoader()
{
    Task<Data> LoadAsync(int id);
}
```

I have two implementations of this interface:

```
class NiceDataBase : ILoader 
{
    public async Task<Data> LoadAsync(int id)
    {
        //this database has async way of fetching the data
        return await NiceDataBaseDriver.LoadDataAsync(id);
    }
}

class NotNiceDataBase : ILoader 
{
    public async Task<Data> LoadAsync(int id)
    {
        //this database's driver does not have aysnc methods, because it's old or done poorly.
        return await Task.Run(() => NotNiceDataBaseDriver.LoadData(id));
    }
}
```

The NotNiceDataBase doesn't provide real async way to load the data, that's why I actually run it on a new thread, which, as I understand, is not really async, because real async does not use a new thread. Is my implementation of NotNiceDataBase a good one then? It kind of cheats the user to think that he is running a real async operation.

What is the optimal way to deal with such situation? I think that the client of NotNiceDataBase should be completely aware what he is doing, otherwise he can't control performance of hiw application well.

My interface could have additional Load method. But in such case, what's the real benefit here? Still LoadAsync of NotNiceDataBase would need to have some implementation. Throwing NotImplementedException is never a good solution I think.

Comment: I would probably add remarks to `NotNiceDatabase` implementation or modify the interface to provide a non-async `Data Load(int id)`.

Comment: I'm not going to answer because of the intricacies of async are something I'm not an expert in. But you can await Task.Yield if you want to remain only implementing an async interface (otherwise do what Daniel mentioned. Or you could use Task.FromResult and make the method not async but my understanding is that both those options have their pit falls

Comment: @DanielShillcock That defeats the point of interface. The consumers of `NiceDataBase` are using the async method. They will expect it to work if they start using `NotNiceDataBase`. Obviously you can't expect them to go change their code to start using `Data Load(int id)` method.

Comment: consumers or customers? Add remarks to say that the implementation is not truly asynchronous. You can't do much about bad design if you don't control it.

Comment: Note that if you do stick with this implementation, you can probably remove `async` and `await` from `LoadAsync` in `NotNiceDatabase`. The *contract* requires you to return a `Task<Data>`. Your `Task.Run` call is clearly producing such an item. No need to add the async machinery in here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever This doesn't really change anything, both ways (returning with or without await) result in the same behaviour on client side. after all, client wants to get the data, so I can await here or not. Client will await anyway. Method code will be a little shorter, that's only benefit of this.

Comment: @Loreno - exactly the point I was making. `LoadAsync` in `NotNiceDatabase` doesn't need `async` and `await` and the client observable behaviour will be (mostly) the same. So why force the compiler to build the async state machine for that method when it's not needed?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - Could you please  say something more about "building async state machine"? I don't really understand

Answer (score 7):

As you know `async` is an implementation detail and you can not define `async` on interfaces. So all you have to do is

```
public class NotNiceDataBase : ILoader
{
    public Task<Data> LoadAsync(int id)
    {
        //this database's driver does not have aysnc methods, because it's old or done poorly.    
        var result = NotNiceDataBaseDriver.LoadData(id);
        return Task.FromResult(result);
     }
}
```

Comment: @pere57: What's the alternative? You write an `IInfoFacade` interface with a `GetAsync` method. You provide implementations for MongoDb, SQL, Oracle . . . 3 years later you have a customer who has to integrate with a weird outdated repository with no async methods. Usage of IInfoFacade is ubiquitous throughout your code base, you can't refactor to add a synchronous method (too many implementations will break) nor can you add a new interface. What do you do in that scenario?

Comment: @EmrahSüngü This solution is an even greater "cheating" - it runs completely synchronously, it  blocks the thread, while method signature makes you think it doesn't block.

Comment: @Loreno, I simply mimic what Microsoft does in their implementation. If MS is fine, I am fine

Comment: @pere57, I do not understand the bold immediately.Docs clearly states that `when the return value of a task is immediately known without *a longer code path.*`. I can provide many references. Please check asp.net core implementations. Many functions return `Task.FromResult` without explicitly using `await`

Comment: @pere57 define quickly enough. By the way how come the longer path is async? It is just returning a task from `Task.Run`

Comment: @pere57, Isnt it `Task.FromResult` immediately returning? By the way I am sorry I wasnt able to post any asp.net  core references since I am on mobile phone and It is too troublesome to use browser now :)

Comment: @pere57, I am sorry but the comments are getting longer. I believe you should have a look at what happens when we use `await` and what happens when we use `async`. Moreover, it may be a good idea to to have a look at what `return immediately means`. If you like, We can talk on another platform :)

Answer (score 5):

Simply run the method synchronously and return a completed task 
e.g.

```
class NotNiceDataBase : ILoader 
{
    public Task<Data> LoadAsync(int id)
    {
        var data = NotNiceDataBaseDriver.LoadData(id);
        return Task.From(data);
    }
}
```

You say

> I think that the client of NotNiceDataBase should be completely aware
>   what he is doing, otherwise he can't control performance of hi(s)
>   application well.

I disagree, *if* performance is an issue **and** *if* they've identified that it's the call to `NotNiceDataBase` *then* they can do something about it.

*elaboration*

Time worrying about how the client is using the interface is *almost certainly*<sup>1</sup> time wasted, and isn't even "premature optimization" but is existential angst over someone else's unknown optimization needs.

<sup>1</sup>Unless you are your own client, then it's still *probably* time wasted.

Comment: How is this answer different from @EmrahSüngü ? Apart from that it will not compile, because there is no such method as `Task.From`

Comment: @FCin I believe we roughly answered around the same time (;^_^A

Comment: @Could you please elaborate on `I disagree, if performance is an issue and if they've identified that it's the call to NotNiceDataBase then they can do something about it.` I would like to know more

Comment: @FCin: Yes,  Emrah Süngü and I posted at more or less the same time.

Comment: `Time worrying about how the client is using the interface is almost certainly1 time wasted, and isn't event "premature optimization" but is existential angst over someone elses unknown optimization needs.` It's not always true especially when you develop your product with some SLA considerations. Anyway even without that it's subject of good manners to let a client know what happens. I'd personally be unpleasantly surprised if I used library with async contracts and it turned out they are actually are synchronous but just wrapped into asynchronous shell and this affected my results.

Comment: @DmytroMukalov: It's time to announce those concerns where the client decides on the type of Db their using, it needs to be flagged that calls to "Not Nice Data Base" are synchronous, then if the client needs to worry about it they worry about it. I'm not a fan of tying myself in knots because an implementation of an interface _might_ have sync methods underneath.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier That's also possible way, another option is explicit contracts.